# Running a custom command in a `gnome-terminal` profile

Tags: 16.04, bash, gnome-terminal

I have created a custom gnome-terminal profile in Ubuntu 16.04 in order to setup a specific development environment. However I can't work out what to enter as the profile's `custom command`.

What I want my new terminal profile to do:

1. Run whatever default scripts the default terminal usually runs (`.bashrc` etc)
2. Run a custom script (eg `$HOME/.dev_profile`)

What should my custom command be?

Comment: You want  that custom script to be ran automatically as soon as you open the terminal with the created profile?

Comment: Yes. Instead of having to run `source $HOME/.dev_profile` manually in the default terminal, I want a terminal profile that runs it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*NOTE: in the following, I've called the custom shell initialization file `.devrc` rather than `.dev_profile` to preserve the distinction between login and non-login shell initialization.*]

Note also that this answer assumes that what you really want to do is **source a custom environment** rather than **run a custom command**.

---

One way to do this would be to create a custom initialization file (`.devrc`, say) that sources the standard files and then adds your customizations e.g.:

```
$ cat ~/.devrc
#
# Custom .bashrc for develeopment terminal profile
# 
if [ -r "/etc/bash.bashrc" ]; then
    . "/etc/bash.bashrc"
fi

if [ -r "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi

# add your dev-specific stuff here
export myvar1=foo
export myvar2=bar
```

Then in your gnome-terminal profile, you can set the Custom Command to use the alternate rc file

```
/bin/bash --rcfile "/home/steeldriver/.devrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `.desktop` file to open a terminal with the desired profile and run a script within such terminal.

**The `.desktop` file:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Edit to add name
Exec=gnome-terminal -e --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME "source $HOME/.dev_profile"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

Note that you can set on the profile settings whether you want the opened terminal to stay open or not, after the script has been completed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - at least if I replace `source $HOME/.dev_profile` with `echo dev_profile` I don't get anything in the new terminal. Is there no way to do this with the terminal profile's `custom command` setting? Changing the `.desktop` file requires me to log out/log back in again in order to test it.