# "Custom command" seems to have no effect in gnome-terminal profile

Tags: gnome-terminal

Per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/908766/) answer I added a custom command in my gnome-terminal profile specifying an rc file as explained in that answer. Specifically, my custom command is `/bin/bash --rcfile "/home/dqbydt/.gitplrc"`. However, it appears to have no effect (the contents of that rc enable [powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), so the prompt changes quite dramatically if the script has been executed). I can source that same rc file manually after the terminal opens, and that does work. So there isn't anything in the rc itself that is suspect.

I have set a new font for that profile and that does change, so the profile itself is indeed getting applied. However the custom command is definitely not getting executed. What can I try? This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Is the *"Run Command as a login shell"* boxed checked, by any chance?

Comment: No, sure isn't. The entirety of the configuration on the Command tab is as follows:
_Run command as a login shell_ : unchecked  
_Run a custom command instead of my shell_ : checked  
_Custom command_ : set as above  
_Preserve working directory_ : set to Shell only  
_When command exits_ : Exit the terminal  

It shouldn't need logout/login to take effect, right?

Comment: Use `ps` to check: is the newly launched program indeed not what you specified in the settings?

Comment: You do launch a _new_ terminal with the given profile, do you? Because if you change profile after launching a terminal, the custom command obviously cannot be applied.

Comment: @egmont Indeed, yes, I am launching a new terminal and then changing the profile (the newly created profile is intentionally not default). I added an `echo` of `$(date)` to a file from the custom-command rc script and that does not get updated. But I can manually source `. /home/dqbydt/.gitplrc` in the new terminal after the profile switch, and that works. The file gets updated; the prompt changes as desired; everything is good.

Comment: You should find the menu entry that launches a _new_ terminal with the profile of your choice. Once a terminal is launched with a certain profile, including a command belonging to that profile, there's no way the command there could be replaced. That part of the profile setting cannot be applied upon profile change.

Comment: Huh, yes, that works! This is a critical piece of information missing in the other answer as well. If you add this as an answer I am happy to accept it.